# Trying to pull in https paths into ffmpeg for node-js running on aws ec2 fails with 'input file does not exist'

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ffmpeg

I have a script set up to load in a video file from an s3 bucket into a node script running on an ec2 instance, but I am having issues trying to get ffmpeg to accept the url. I know that my aws-sdk integration is working ok as I can read objects and write objects to the bucket, and I am generating a signed url to the object in order to easily pass the path through but it seems to be failing with an 'input file does not exist' error.

If I use this generated signed path in a browser however, the video file can be found.

Has anyone else come across this issue? I could probably try and pipe through the external file to a new file local to the ec2 instance but if I can get round that extra step that would be great!

Comment: in a browser, fetch is being used to get the URL to the resource ( file ).  node-fetch package should let u run same process ( fetch ) server-side on the same input ( URL ) and get same result on the file.. CORS issues will b likely to arise but that will just involve addition of headers to the Fetch

Comment: cheers! will give that a try

Comment: Hey there, looks like that allowed me to pipe into a file on the ec2 instance and pass that to ffmpeg. I just seem to have some other problems with ffmpeg now, but I don't think they fall under the umbrella of my original question.